# Plotting a graph from dataframe with multiple csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have 2 csv files

file1.csv

```
,DATE,DAY,OPEN,2PM,CLOSE,STATUS
0,2021-05-18,Tuesday,538.8,530.45,530.8,0
1,2021-05-19,Wednesday,530.65,532.6,536.85,0
2,2021-05-20,Thursday,536.95,537.05,536.35,1
3,2021-05-21,Friday,538.0,538.2,537.55,1
4,2021-05-24,Monday,537.3,535.05,532.85,1
5,2021-05-25,Tuesday,535.9,531.35,529.65,1
6,2021-05-26,Wednesday,532.95,530.55,532.1,0
7,2021-05-27,Thursday,532.95,529.65,529.85,0
```

file2.csv

```
,DATE,DAY,OPEN,2PM,CLOSE,STATUS
0,2021-05-18,Tuesday,538.8,530.45,530.8,1
1,2021-05-19,Wednesday,530.65,532.6,536.85,0
2,2021-05-20,Thursday,536.95,537.05,536.35,1
3,2021-05-21,Friday,538.0,538.2,537.55,1
4,2021-05-24,Monday,537.3,535.05,532.85,2
5,2021-05-25,Tuesday,535.9,531.35,529.65,1
6,2021-05-26,Wednesday,532.95,530.55,532.1,0
7,2021-05-27,Thursday,532.95,529.65,529.85,0
```

file3.csv

```
,DATE,DAY,OPEN,2PM,CLOSE,STATUS
0,2021-05-18,Tuesday,538.8,530.45,530.9,0
1,2021-05-19,Wednesday,530.65,532.6,536.85,1
2,2021-05-20,Thursday,536.95,537.05,536.35,0
3,2021-05-21,Friday,538.0,538.2,537.55,1
4,2021-05-24,Monday,537.3,535.05,532.85,1
5,2021-05-25,Tuesday,535.9,531.35,529.65,0
6,2021-05-26,Wednesday,532.95,530.55,532.1,0
7,2021-05-27,Thursday,532.95,529.65,529.85,1
```

Graph for an INDIVIDUAL csv file can be plotted using

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
df.groupby('DAY')['STATUS'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack().plot.bar()
```

which shows plot as

[image]

This plot has 5 twinBARS(Monday, Tue, Wed, etc) for one file.

But, I want to plot data for "Monday" from all 3 files in a single plot. Can anyone let me know how can we do that with multiple files?

IT MEANS, PLOT WILL HAVE 3 TWIN BARS. EACH TWIN BAR WILL REPRESENT MONDAYS from each file
e.g.

```
Monday from file1.csv
Monday from file2.csv
Monday from file3.csv
```

And I want to plot this graph for Monday for all 3 files.

Comment: Is there any reason for which question has been downvoted? Or just because one don't want to answer or don't know the answer, its downvoted?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question, but maybe you could just join those three files with `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])` and finally you'd use the code that you provided?

Comment: Concat will not work as I need Monday for each file as bar and not combined

Comment: Then you should add more details to your question, as it's not clear what you want (as least to me)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Added, please check bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `FILE` column for each `df` before concatenating them. Then filter by the desired day (`Tuesday` in this example) and group by both `DAY` and `FILE`:

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv').assign(FILE=1)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv').assign(FILE=2)
df3 = pd.read_csv('file3.csv').assign(FILE=3)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).reset_index(drop=True)

# or concat via generator
# df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f'file{i}.csv').assign(FILE=i) for i in (1,2,3).reset_index(drop=True))

(df[df.DAY.eq('Tuesday')]
    .groupby(['DAY', 'FILE'])['STATUS']
    .value_counts(normalize=True)
    .unstack().plot.bar())
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
```

[image: tuesdays per file]

---

To filter by a given `threshold`, save the value counts to an intermediate `counts` df and use that to filter:

```py
day, threshold = 'Tuesday', 0.8
counts = df[df.DAY.eq(day)].groupby(['DAY', 'FILE'])['STATUS'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack()
counts[counts > threshold].plot.bar()
```

[image: tuesdays per file above threshold]

Comment: great bro. one question, how can we only plot those Tue which has value more than 0.8? (for 0 or for 1)

Comment: aha okay...Thank you so much bro!